# OS X's hidden preferences disappeared after Mavericks upgrade?

Tags: mac, terminal, preferences

In past OS X versions, I used some commands to set preferences on my Mac.

For example, I used the following command to enable selection of text in Quick Look:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool TRUE;
```

…and the following command to create a stack on the Dock of recently-used apps:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add '{ "tile-data" = { "list-type" = 1; }; "tile-type" = "recents-tile"; }'
```

In my Mac that I just upgraded they are all working as before, but in other Mac, which I initialised before upgrading they don't work. Does somebody knows a way to make them work again or an alternative for them?

Comment: What happens if you rerun those defaults commands after the OS upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a stack on the Dock of recently-used apps I solved using Thinkertool (http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) which allow to enable lot of hidden preferences including the stack of recently-used apps.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those still work for me, but you do sometimes need to run defaults commands again after upgrading OS X. If you run the commands again, quit and reopen applications to apply the changes:

```
killall Dock Finder
```

(If you also want to enable selecting text in Quick Look windows shown from other applications than Finder, you can use `defaults write -g QLEnableTextSelection -bool true` instead of `defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool true`.)

Comment: Your version for QLEnableTextSelection has worked but I still  can't generate the stack for recent App or disable NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud ( defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false )...

Comment: I tried pasting working .plist in initialized Mac but it still don't work...

Comment: @Matte.Car Did you quit and reopen applications to apply the changes? `defaults write NSGlobalDomain  NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false` still works for me.

Comment: no, wrong, NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud works for me too. The only thing that I can't do is to create a stack of recent launched apps...